# python using post method for upload file

Tags: python

I have a problem with importing file to calendar over wcap protocol. In documentation http://docs.sun.com/source/816-6416-10/pr10WCAP.html#26125 is said that i should use POST method. I have trayed but with no positiv result. I have no idea hov to forced it to work with python

Comment: Please post any code you have tried

Comment: "with no positiv result"  Meaningless.  Vague.  Unanswerable.  I can't guess what "no positiv result" could even mean.  I'm guessing that you have syntax errors from bad indentation.  How'd I do?

Comment: What server are you connecting to? The Sun version?

Answer (score 0):

The `wcap` reference you provide contains example `POST` data.
Using the [`urllib2.urlopen()`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen) function with `POST` data is straightforward.

> `urllib2.urlopen(url[, data][, timeout])`
>
> Open the URL url, which can be either a string or a Request object.
>
> data may be a string specifying additional data to send to the server, or None if no such data is needed. Currently HTTP requests are the only ones that use data; **the HTTP request will be a POST instead of a GET when the data parameter is provided**. data should be a buffer in the standard application/x-www-form-urlencoded format. The urllib.urlencode() function takes a mapping or sequence of 2-tuples and returns a string in this format.